# Center and include links in list - css

Tags: html, css

I'm about to change from using table to list but have some issues:

I can't seem to get the list centered on the screen. What I'm looking for is for the list to not cover the whole screen horizontally. I also try to get the list and the text centered, and have the text link.

So far so good. But how do I get not only the text in the list centered, but the list itself centered on the screen? I've tried a bunch of different ways, but haven't found anything that works.

**What I have now is a table**

```css
table {
  }
  table {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 50%;
    margin:0 auto;
  }
  p.padding {
  padding-left: 70%;
}

p.padding2 {
  padding-left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container w3-justify">
    <table class="w3-table w3-striped w3-hoverable w3-black">
    <thead>
        <tr class="w3-black">
        <th style="align-text: center">
        <th><h2>FIND MY ART</h2></th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="w3-black"><h3><p class="padding"><a href="https://opensea.io/creepybits">OpenSea</h3></a></p></td>
      <td class="w3-black"><h3><p class="padding2"><a href="https://rarible.com/creepybits">Rarible</h3></a></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="w3-black"><h3><p class="padding"><a href="https://foundation.app/@creepybits">Foundation</h3></a></p></td>
      <td class="w3-black"><h3><p class="padding2"><a href="https://www.bakeryswap.org/#/usercenter/0x021E8A6bEC4300362165546f2F0F7E3baACf3aDe?artist=Creepybits">BakerySwap</h3></a></p></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

But it doesn't look good and gets all messed up at smaller screens. What I'm, looking for is something similar to this template I found. But I only want one of the lists, and for the list to be centered (without bullets or numbers).

The template list looks like this
[Current template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvEV6.png)

What I'm trying to do is this.
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCLfO.png)

Comment: Please insert your css as well. And if you're using a UI/Frontend library for styling, then include the link for that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is better to use grid in this case, you can find more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

```css
html{background-color:black}
.wrapper{
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:50px;
  width:300px;
  text-align:center;
}
.header{
  padding: 15px;
  color:white;
  font-size:23px;
  background-color:grey;
}
.grid-container{
  grid-template-colums:auto;
}
.grid-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color:#CDCDCD;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> 
  <div class="header">List</div>
  <div class="grid-container">   
    <div class="grid-item">item one</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item two</div>
    <div class="grid-item">item three</div>  
    <div class="grid-item">item four</div>
    <div class="grid-item" style="padding:20px!important">$54</div>
    <div class="grid-item" style="padding:20px!important;background-color:#c0c0c0"><button style="cursor:pointer">sign up</button></div>  
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated in HTML5.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit unclear in the thread start. I have edited some.